# Why second input from client side is marked as wrong input?

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

I have created a client server application in C (TCP) and my codes are all working find (functions). However, from the client side, when I enter a command, for example "time", the server returns the correct response, but on second time executing the same command, the server returns "invalid command"

This is my server.c, creating of the different threads and all are working perfectly.

```
void menu(int connfd, int i)
{
    while(TRUE)
    {
        userMenu();
        write(connfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        //read command
        bzero(buffer, MAX);
        read(connfd, buffer, MAX);
        
        if (CheckValidCommand(buffer) != TRUE)
        {
            bzero(buffer, MAX);
            strcpy(buffer, "Invalid Command\n");
            write(connfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        }
        else
        {
            char* token = strtok(buffer, " ");

            char command[20];
            strcpy(command, ConvertToLower(token));
            
            if (strcmp(command, "join") == 0)
            {
                Join(connfd, buffer);
            }
            else if (strcmp(command, "whois") == 0)
            {
                //Get username                
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                
                bzero(buffer, MAX);
                strcpy(buffer, WhoIs(connfd, token));

                write(connfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            }
            else if (strcmp(command, "msg") == 0)
            {
                //Get username                
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");

                Chat(connfd, token, buffer);
            }
            else if (strcmp(command, "time") == 0)
            {
                bzero(buffer, MAX);
                strcpy(buffer, GetTime());
                write(connfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            }
            else if (strcmp(command, "alive") == 0)
            {
                Alive(connfd);
            }
            else if (strcmp(command, "quit") == 0)
            {
                Quit(connfd);
            }
        }
    }

    CheckConnectedUser();
}
```

And this is my client.c

```
int CheckValidCommand(char buff[])
{
    int isValid = FALSE;
    int wordCount = 0;
    char tokens[5][20];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buff) - 1; i++)
    {
        if (buff[i] == ' ')
        {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    wordCount++;

    char* token = strtok(buff, " ");
    token = ConvertToLower(token);

    if (strcmp(token, "join") == 0)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        int totalTokens = 0;
            
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (strlen(token) > 20)
                return FALSE;
            
            strcpy(tokens[totalTokens], token);

            totalTokens++;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        totalTokens--;

        char* Name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
        char* Username = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);

        //Get UserName
        strcpy(Username, tokens[1]);

        strcpy(Name, tokens[2]);
        strcat(Name, " ");

        //Get name
        for (int x = 2; x < totalTokens - 1; x++)
        {
            strcat(Name, " ");
            strcat(Name, tokens[x]);
        }
        strcat(Name, tokens[totalTokens]);

        if (strlen(Name) > 20 || strlen(Username) > 20)
            return FALSE;
        else
            return TRUE;
    }
    else if (strcmp(token, "whois") == 0)
    {
        if (wordCount > 2)
            return FALSE;

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

        if (strlen(token) > 20)
            return FALSE;

        return TRUE;
    }
    else if (strcmp(token, "msg") == 0)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");

        if (strlen(token) > 20)
            return FALSE;

        char txt[MAX];
        
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            strcat(txt, token);
            strcat(txt, " ");
        }

        strcpy(txt, RemoveExtraSpace(txt));

        if (strlen(txt) > 256)
            return FALSE;

        return TRUE;
    }
    else if (strcmp(token, "time") == 0)
    {
        if (strtok(NULL, " ") == NULL)
            return TRUE;
        else 
            return FALSE;
    }
    else if (strcmp(token, "alive") == 0)
    {
        if (strtok(NULL, " ") == NULL)
            return TRUE;
        else 
            return FALSE;
    }
    else if (strcmp(token, "quit") == 0)
    {
        if (strtok(NULL, " ") == NULL)
            return TRUE;
        else 
            return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Run with : \n");
        printf("\t./client ip_address port_number\n");
        printf("\t\tWhere ipaddress is ipv4 address\n");
        printf("\t\tWhere port_number is open port number\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        int sockfd, connfd, n;
        char currChar;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
        char ipaddress[20];
        memcpy(ipaddress, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        
        // socket create and varification
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd == -1) {
            printf("socket creation failed!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    
        // assign IP, PORT
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        inet_pton(AF_INET, ipaddress, &(servaddr.sin_addr));
        
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    
        // connect the client socket to server socket
        if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0)
        {
            printf("connection with the server failed!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        
        while (TRUE)
        {
            //read menu
            bzero(buffer, MAX);
            read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            printf("%s", buffer);

            bzero(buffer, MAX);

            n = 0;
            
            while ((buffer[n++] = getchar()) != '\n');
            buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;

            write(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

            //read response
            bzero(buffer, MAX);
            read(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }


        // close the socket
        close(sockfd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, try to create a minimal reproducible example, starting, for example, by removing all other commands, since you say that just 2 occurrence of "time" are enough, but including the context (#include, main of the server, etc.). It will make possible for us to try your code, and to be able to help us more easily. Plus, more often than not, that simple exercise of trying to string the code of everything that is not related to the bug... would make you find the bug.

Comment: My first thought would be that you have some trailing spaces or newlines from the first "time" that prevent to parse correctly the second. But I can't be sure of that, without ability to try, and without spending too much time analyzing your long code.

Comment: Client code "join": ` `if (strlen(Name) > 20 || strlen(Username) > 20)`... It does no good to first overrun a buffer, then to test if the buffer has been overrun... You've possibly entered the Twilight Zone of UB, and anything is possible after that...